# count of different ids based on flag values group by first two rows

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

So, I've got a table that looks like that:

```
card_no trx_date    product_id  flag

 1    17/09/2015      1111    CANDIDATE

 1    17/09/2015      2222    NO

 1    17/09/2015      3333    CANDIDATE

 1    18/09/2015      2222    NULL

 1    18/09/2015      3333    CANDIDATE

 2    17/09/2015      1111    YES

 2    17/09/2015      2222    CANDIDATE

 2    18/09/2015      3333    CANDIDATE
```

What I want is to count the product_id based on the following criteria:

- For the same card and trx_date, if there is a flag that is set to 'Yes', then count the product_id that has the 'Yes' flag.
- For the same card and trx_date, if there is a flag that is set to 'No', then count ANY product_id of this card+trx_date that has the 'candidate' flag.
- For the same card and trx_date, if there is a flag that is set to 'No', but there is no other reconrd for this card and trx_date, don't count any product.
- For the same card and trx_date, if there is a flag that is set to 'Null', then count ANY product_id of this card+trx_date that has the 'Candidate' flag.

What I want to end up with is something like this:

```
Product_id|Counts

      1111| 657

      2222| 456

...
```

I hope it makes sense.

Comment: Hi, can i ask, How would we know if theres a record for a certain card and trx_date?then, why do you only have one expected column for count?You posted 4 criterias which doesnt make sense.Are we supposed to sum up those criterias? lastly, can you please make an expected output based on the table that is posted rather than the actual table.its confusing, your expected count is 100000 plus, but you only have 8 rows. =)

Comment: Hi, I edited the expected counts. I posted 8 rows, cause I wanted to cover the four different scenarios. And yes, we are supposed to sum up all product_id counts from all scenarios based on the flag and the scenarios I posted. Thanks

Comment: i see, but still your count should be based on the 8 rows you have posted.